# Add array of files client side to ASPX wizard next step

Tags: javascript, asp.net, aspwizard

I am try to determine if it is possible to send an array of files when "Next" is called from an asp:wizard.

I had this working previously with a simple  however I was forced to change it because you cannot remove individual files from the FileObject. Instead I am now adding any files added via the input to an array to get around this.

However I am now in a position where I am not sure how to add these files to the form data on submit.

EDIT:

```
<asp:Wizard ID="wizImport" runat="server" OnFinishButtonClick="wizImport_FinishButtonClick" OnPreviousButtonClick="wizImport_PreviousButtonClick" OnNextButtonClick="wizImport_NextButtonClick">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="wizImportStep1" runat="server">
```

Within this wizard step I have a custom user control that includes a HTML input of type="file" and this screen requires a user to be add multiple files to the page, but be able to remove individual files.

```
<input class="fileInput" type="file" id="imgInputFile" data-label="imgInputFileLabel" runat="server" style="display: none;"/>
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="imgInputFile" class="uploadButton" Text="Select"></asp:Label>
```

To get around this I currently have an event listener that on change, copies the file(s) sent to a new array client side array. I need to add this client side list of files to the top level form created by the wizard when they click the next button.

```
// Setup the listener on the specific file input control
var fileInput = $('#imgInputFile.ClientID');
fileInput.each(function () {
    this.addEventListener('change', handleInputFileSelect, false);
});
// In this function, I just grab the file and add it to a var called uploadedFiles which is an array
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would expand your question to include the relevant code of what you've tried thus far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry, edited for a bit more clarity.

Comment: One problem you might be having is with your fileInput.each. The HTML spec says you're not supposed to have multiple elements with the same id, but you seem to be planning on having multiple `#imgInputFile` elements. If the `.ClientID` elements are supposed to be contained within the `#imgInputFile` element, then you would want a space between them. If not, there is a quirk in jQuery that will allow you to find multiple ids by doing something like `$('[id=imgInputFile].ClientId')`. But it will only find the first if you use the `#` operator.